# What can be the variation name of this complete game which falls on ECO C02

Tags: analysis, french-defense

When I had looked at

> http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessopening?eco=C02

there are 4,893 variations found for ECO C02.

Is this variation can have some name from among 4893 variation, sorry for asking from the count I just asked as its in ECO. However I want some better analysis for this game.

Except one pawn move which I had planned to do before on its turn.- `10 .. g5`, I tried my ability well, rather maybe not atlast.

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.01.11"]
[White "Meketrex"]
[Black "anandsadasivam"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "C02"]
[WhiteElo "713"]
[BlackElo "668"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[Termination "Meketrex won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "4Q3/bb3Q2/p1k1p3/Pp1pP2p/1Pp2P1P/2P3P1/R3q3/KN6 b - - 3 37"]

1.e4 {[%clk 0:09:59]} e6 {[%clk 0:09:54]} 2.d4 {[%clk 0:09:54]} d5 {[%clk 0:09:47]} 3.e5 {[%clk 0:09:46]} Nc6 {[%clk 0:09:25]} 4.g3 {[%clk 0:09:42]} Bb4+ {[%clk 0:09:08]} 5.c3 {[%clk 0:09:36]} Ba5 {[%clk 0:09:03]} 6.b4 {[%clk 0:09:28]} Bb6 {[%clk 0:08:58]} 7.a4 {[%clk 0:08:55]} a6 {[%clk 0:08:49]} 8.a5 {[%clk 0:08:47]} Ba7 {[%clk 0:08:47]} 9.Bg2 {[%clk 0:08:37]} b5 {[%clk 0:08:39]} 10.Qg4 {[%clk 0:07:56]} g5 {[%clk 0:08:34]} 11.Bxg5 {[%clk 0:07:53]} Qd7 {[%clk 0:08:14]} 12.Nf3 {[%clk 0:07:09]} h6 {[%clk 0:08:10]} 13.Bf6 {[%clk 0:07:00]} Nxf6 {[%clk 0:08:00]} 14.exf6 {[%clk 0:06:58]} h5 {[%clk 0:07:54]} 15.Qg7 {[%clk 0:06:55]} Rf8 {[%clk 0:07:31]} 16.Ng5 {[%clk 0:06:53]} Bb7 {[%clk 0:07:21]} 17.Nh7 {[%clk 0:06:50]} O-O-O {[%clk 0:07:16]} 18.Nxf8 {[%clk 0:06:48]} Rxf8 {[%clk 0:07:12]} 19.Qxf8+ {[%clk 0:06:46]} Nd8 {[%clk 0:07:10]} 20.Qh6 {[%clk 0:06:22]} e5 {[%clk 0:06:58]} 21.dxe5 {[%clk 0:06:08]} Qf5 {[%clk 0:06:55]} 22.f4 {[%clk 0:05:57]} Ne6 {[%clk 0:06:43]} 23.Qh8+ {[%clk 0:05:16]} Kd7 {[%clk 0:06:36]} 24.h4 {[%clk 0:03:59]} c5 {[%clk 0:06:32]} 25.Bh3 {[%clk 0:03:54]} Qe4+ {[%clk 0:06:27]} 26.Kd2 {[%clk 0:03:33]} Qxh1 {[%clk 0:06:13]} 27.Bxe6+ {[%clk 0:03:14]} fxe6 {[%clk 0:06:05]} 28.f7 {[%clk 0:02:50]} Qg2+ {[%clk 0:06:02]} 29.Kc1 {[%clk 0:02:42]} Qg1+ {[%clk 0:05:55]} 30.Kb2 {[%clk 0:02:40]} Qf2+ {[%clk 0:05:49]} 31.Ka3 {[%clk 0:02:38]} Qc2 {[%clk 0:05:14]} 32.Ra2 {[%clk 0:02:27]} Qa4+ {[%clk 0:05:04]} 33.Kb2 {[%clk 0:02:22]} Qd1 {[%clk 0:04:41]} 34.f8=Q {[%clk 0:02:17]} Qe2+ {[%clk 0:04:38]} 35.Ka1 {[%clk 0:02:12]} c4 {[%clk 0:04:17]} 36.Qf7+ {[%clk 0:02:09]} Kc6 {[%clk 0:04:12]} 37.Qhe8# {[%clk 0:01:40]} 
1-0
```

Here is the fen

```
[fen "4Q3/bb3Q2/p1k1p3/Pp1pP2p/1Pp2P1P/2P3P1/R3q3/KN6 b - - 3 37"]
```

Comment: The opening is probably best described as a kind of [Nimzowitsch Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimzowitsch_Defence), which could come about from the move order 1.e4 Nc6 2.d4 d5 3.e5 e6. The move 3...e6 has been played (by Nimzowitsch himself) but the usual move is 3...Bf5 to develop the bishop outside the pawn chain. However, at this level of play, opening variations are irrelevant. Why did you play 10...g5 giving away the pawn, instead of 10...g6 or 10...Kf8? Learning to count how many pieces are attacking a square is more important than learning names of opening variations.

Comment: I vote we call this variation the Sadasivam Defense in the French-Nimzovitch. It's the only thing I can think of why this was asked. :)

Comment: Your 18...Rxf8 is really hard to understand. You are down material and your position is already hopelessly lost, but that's no reason to trade a rook for a knight. (You know that a rook is better than a knight, right?) Instead, you could play 18...Qe8, defending your f7 (you *don't* want to help White get a passed pawn on f6) and attacking the white knight, which has nothing better than to retreat 19.Nh7, and then you could play 19...e5 to free your queenside pieces.You're [still gonna lose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdEoputkE98) but you could at least *try* to put up a fight.

Answer (score 3):

C02 is the French advance variation. *If handled properly* it is characterized by white gaining space in the center with white pawns typically on b2, c3, d4, e5, f4. The center is closed and black is challenging the white pawn chain from the side playing c5 and often f6. Only after c5, the black knight will go to c6 in order to increase the pressure on the white d4 pawn.

Now in your game black does none of this and allows white to expand even more creating no counterplay. Since 3. ... Nc6 is already a bad move (c5 is best and by far the most popular) this whole line does not have a name. Note that attacking the center with pieces only (e.g. with Nc6) does not pose any problems for white as after c3, black will not be able to take on d4 with knight or bishop without losing material.